# Could not convert string to float: 'financial_year' in excel data set

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('number-of-households-billed-for-upgrading.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
plt.plot(x,y, label='Loaded from file!')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('No. of Household Billed for Upgrading')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

There are two columns in this dataset; Financial Year and No. of Households
How do I solve the problem of converting the financial year to float?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your financial year data is stored in `x`, you can map all your year string values to `float` type (or `int` type) using a list comprehension as follows and then plot as usual

```
x = [float(i) for i in x]
plt.plot(x,y, label='Loaded from file!')
```

**Alternatively** you can simply map your complete list at once using `map` function

```
x = list(map(float, x)) # list(map(int, x))
plt.plot(x,y, label='Loaded from file!')
```

If the same error occurs for the `y` values, do the same for them too.

Comment: I tried your method but the same error occured. This is what I did:  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('number-of-households-billed-for-upgrading.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
x = list(map(float, x)) # list(map(int, x))
y = list(map(float, y)) # list(map(int, y))
plt.plot(x,y, label='Loaded from file!')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('No. of Household Billed for Upgrading')
plt.legend()
plt.show()